# Expected primary expression before ';' token

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct PROCESS{
        int priority;
        int lifecycle;
        int ttl; 

}process1,process2,process3,process4,process5,process6;

main(){
       PROCESS *waiting_queue;
       waiting_queue = process1;      //this is were I get the error. 
       waiting_queue =(PROCESS *)malloc(6*sizeof(PROCESS));
       if(!waiting_queue){printf("no memory for waiting queue   "); exit(0);}


       getch();       
}
```

I am trying to create a struct array with pointer. I am getting the error. Expected primary expression before ';' token

Comment: You're mixing up the declaration of a *type* and a *struct* in a rather broken way. AFAICT, `process1` in the line where you get the error is a *type*, not a structure, rendering the statement somewhat illegal.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your struct object from (process1 to process6).

Let me give you an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student 
{
  int id;
  char name[20];
  float percentage;
} status;

int main() 
{
  status record;
  record.id=1;
  strcpy(record.name, "Orcun");
  record.percentage = 86.5;
  printf(" Id is: %d \n", record.id);
  printf(" Name is: %s \n", record.name);
  printf(" Percentage is: %f \n", record.percentage);
  return 0;
}
```

This is why you are getting your error in your main function. So you should create your struct object like:

```
process1 processOrcun;
```

You can also check here : https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-structures-unions-typedef

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problem, but the one causing your error is that you don't define a *type* `PROCESS`, but a *structure* with that name.

When you use `typedef` to define a structure type, the type-name comes *after* the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
} PROCESS;
```

The error you have is because you define e.g. `process1` as a *type*, so the assignment (making a pointer point to a type) doesn't make any sense.

---

Another, and unrelated, problem is how you define the `main` function. It must be defined to return an `int` (even if your declaration does that implicitly, it's good to do it explicitly) and to either have `void` for argument or an integer and an array of pointers to `char`. In your case it should look like

```
int main(void) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend; I did it as you instructed but giving the same error.

Comment: @mfd What is the type of `waiting_queue`? What is the type of `process1`? Are the types compatible (answer is no)? So no you won't get the *same* error, but a different one. Also, that assignment is useless since you then directly reassign `waiting_queue`.

Comment: their types are PROCESS. your idea inspired me and I found the solution; 
waiting_queue = &process1; THANK YOU.

Comment: @mfd Not quite. The type of `waiting_queue` is `PROCESS*` which is *very* different from the type of `process1` which is `PROCESS`. That's why you need the address-of operator `&`. And again, why do that assignment if you are just going to reassign `waiting_queue` in the very next statement?